# How many distinct numbers can I get mod 8

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

so I have the following $(0,1\ \text{or}\ 4)+(0,1\ \text{or}\ 4)+(0,1\ \text{or}\ 4)$ I want to see how many distinct numbers can I get mod $8$ by adding from this list 3 times for example I got so far 7 possible answers am I missing anything ? Is there a way I can count how many solutions can I get?

$1 + 1 + 4 \equiv 6 \pmod 8$

$0 + 0 + 0 \equiv 0 \pmod 8$

$0 + 1 + 1 \equiv 2 \pmod 8$

$0 + 1 + 4 \equiv 5 \pmod 8$

$1 + 1 + 1 \equiv 3 \pmod 8$

$1 + 4 + 4 \equiv 1 \pmod 8$

$4 + 4 + 4 \equiv 4 \pmod 8$

Comment: Looks ok to me .

Comment: There are only 10 unique combinations, so by exhaustion we could verify these are the only possibilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could prove that you can't get $7\bmod 8$, which you can do by considering everything modulo $4$ and then showing that it doesn't work modulo $8$.

Also a more structured approach to your sums would help you to be confident that you have everything. There are not that many - you can list the nondecreasing sums, because every possible sum is equivalent to one in non-decreasing order.

$0+0+0; 0+0+1; 0+0+4; 0+1+1; 0+1+4; 0+4+4; 1+1+1; 1+1+4; 1+4+4; 4+4+4$

Anything you don't get from those can't be got.

Answer (score 1):

You are not missing anything.  You can't obtain $7$ (mod $8$) with just $0$ and $1$, and using a $4$ leaves you to get $3$ with just two more numbers.